# Constant running control service on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, udp

I need to create a service, in Android, that constantly listens to UDP messages (either broadcast or unicast). Service need to work all the time and never die.

Current solution that I stick with - service, that started by **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** with startWakefulService. Receiver is registered programatically in main activity of the application, that starts service.
Also, to prevent service from being killed or suspended I used *START_STICKY* and plenty of **WakeLock**s (to prevent CPU from falling asleep), **WifiLock**s(to prevent wifi module from falling asleep) and **MulticastLock**s(to prevent blocking UDP broadcasts while device screen is locked). Main problem with wakelocks that I have - I don't know from which thread I need to create it (currently service starts separate thread for UDP packets receiving, so for now I created them from every thread I have). I know about battery drain that wakelocks can create, but it doesn't matter as in the my case device will be almost constantly charged.

Main problem that I currently experiencing - phone still stops receiving broadcast (and I assume that unicasts also) after some time after the screen was locked (I tested my solution on **Samsung Galaxy S7** and **S6**). So, the question is - how do I keep CPU and network alive forever, by any means possible?

Comment: `Service need to work all the time and never die.` mission inpossible: if user wants to kill the service nothing can prevent that

Comment: "that started by WakefulBroadcastReceiver with startWakefulService" -- since you seem to be managing your own `WakeLock`, there is no value in using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. "to prevent service from being killed or suspended I used START_STICKY" -- `START_STICKY` does not prevent the user or Android from terminating your process. It *does* indicate that you would like for your process and service to be restarted at some time in the future, if they are terminated.

Comment: "problem with wakelocks that I have - I don't know from which thread I need to create it" -- a `WakeLock` is a process-level control mechanism. Create and acquire one, in whatever thread makes sense. "how do I keep CPU and network alive forever, by any means possible?" -- stop using Android and use an embedded Linux distribution.

Comment: @pskink it's software for exhibitions, so, in general case, user not allowed to do anything with phone.

Comment: so simply start your thread in any component that is not affected by any termination (beside of physical process termination): let it be an `Application` class, `ContentProvider` or even a good, old "singleton" object